# Achieve C casting using x86 mov instructions

Tags: c, assembly, casting, x86, mov

I'm reading the book "Computer Systems: A Programmer's Perspective". Right now I'm not really sure I understand when to use the different mov instructions. Here's the exercise:

> Practice Problem 3.4
>
> Assume variables v and p declared with types
>
> src_t v;
>
> dest_t *p;
>
> where src_t and dest_t are data types declared with typedef. We wish
>   to use the appropriate data movement instruction to implement the
>   operation
>
> *p = (dest_t) v;
>
> where v is stored in the appropriately named portion of register %eax
>   (i.e., %eax, %ax, or %al), while pointer p is stored in register %edx.
>
> For the following combinations of src_t and dest_t, write a line of
>   assembly code that does the appropriate transfer. Recall that when
>   performing a cast that involves both a size change and a change of
>   “signedness” in C, the operation should change the signedness first
>   (Section 2.2.6).

I'm checking my solutions against [this blog post](http://rooftrellen.com/blog/computer-systems-a-programmers-perspective-chapter-3-practice-problem/) and I'm not quite sure I understand problem 3:

```
src_t       dest_t      My Solution              Blog's Solution

char        unsigned    movzbl %al, (%edx)     movsbl %al, (%edx)
```

Number 3: I use movzbl while the blog's author uses movsbl. I don't understand the reasoning of movzbl vs movsbl in this case... If the char is a negative you'll end up with a wrong number either way, can anyone clarify why movsbl is the correct choice here?

Comment: That depends entirely whether `char` is signed or unsigned. That is implementation-defined, so both solutions are equally correct, given the matching implementation.

Comment: @Jester I think `char` is signed in this case, other problems have `unsigned char` so I think the lack of it means this one is signed.

Comment: If `char` is signed, you need to use `movsbl` to sign extend it. For example, if your char value is `-1` you want the `unsigned int` value to be `0xffffffff` (this is mandated by the C standard).

Comment: I see... It wasn't quite clear for me what the rules were in this case. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Recall that when performing a cast that involves both a size change
>   and a change of “signedness” in C, the operation should change the
>   signedness first (Section 2.2.6).

Unless I'm misreading it, this sentence appears to conflict with what he gives as the correct answer.

That rule would mean that, starting with signed char:

- signed char
- -> unsigned char
- -> unsigned int

So the size conversion is from unsigned char to unsigned int, so `movz` would be appropriate.  Presumably the rule is wrong (doesn't match what C actually specifies), and `movs` really is what a C compiler would use.

Jester's comment says that the unsigned int value of a `-1` char value is required to be `0xffffffff`, so it looks like that last sentence of the practice problem about order of converting signedness and size is the problem.

Comment: Book errata: Practice Problem 3.4. The last sentence of the problem statement should state “... the operation should change the size first ....”